# biblatex-mla bibliography: one redundant dot in second entry by same author (@collection)

Tags: biblatex, punctuation, mla-style

when quoting two collections by the same author, biblatex-mla puts an extra dot before the title in the references entry, as may be seen here:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=mla]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@COLLECTION{adorno-gs10.2,
  editor = {Rolf Tiedemann},
  year = {2003},
  maintitle = {Gesammelte Schriften Bd. 10.2},
  mainsubtitle = {Kulturkritik und Gesellschaft II. Eingriffe. Stichworte},
  publisher = {Suhrkamp},
  location = {Frankfurt am Main},
  author = {Theodor W. Adorno},
  howpublished = {Print},
  options = {useeditor=false},
  owner = {jakob},
  shortauthor = {{In: GS 10.2}},
  timestamp = {30.03.2012}
}

@COLLECTION{adorno-gs8,
  editor = {Rolf Tiedemann},
  year = {2003},
  maintitle = {Gesammelte Schriften Bd. 8},
  mainsubtitle = {Soziologische Schriften I},
  publisher = {Suhrkamp},
  location = {Frankfurt am Main},
  author = {Theodor W. Adorno},
  howpublished = {Print},
  options = {useeditor=false},
  owner = {jakob},
  shortauthor = {{In: GS 8}},
  timestamp = {30.03.2012}
}

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Do you know any way to avoid that or is it even caused by an error in my bib entries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issues with punctuation sometimes crop up in the biblatex-mla style. This is mostly due to the fact that it hasn't been updated since the time of biblatex 1.0.

Your particular problem isn't present with biblatex 1.0. With biblatex 1.7 it seems biblatex-mla's definition of `\bibnamedash` sets too much punctuation. Here's an excerpt from `mla.bbx`:

```
\renewcommand*{\bibnamedash}{%
  \mbox{%
    \mlanamedash%
    \iffieldundef{nameaddon}%
      {\unspace\newunitpunct}%
      {\unspace\addspace}%
  }%
}
```

The `collection` entry types are handled with the `book` bibliography driver. It expects `maintitle` to be used *only* in addition to `title`. If the `nameaddon` and `title` fields are missing, the driver will output too many dots.

So you have three options:

1. Use [biblatex 1.0](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45676/4483) until biblatex-mla gets updated. This will spare you from resolving other incompatibilities the style has with newer biblatex versions. Any remaining punctuation issues can likely be resolved by loading the hyperref package (after biblatex).
2. Use the `maintitle` (`mainsubtitle`) field only when you're already using `title` (`subtitle`). Same goes for `booktitle` and `booksubtitle`. Note that your `collection` entries appear different in other styles. The `biblatex-examples.bib` demonstrate conventional use of `collection` and `incollection`. Details on these entry types and `crossref` inheritance can be found in the biblatex manual.
3. Edit the `\bibnamedash` command.

For (3), the following should give you no dots (like the standard biblatex styles).

```
\renewcommand*{\bibnamedash}{\mlanamedash\nopunct}
```

This should give you exactly one dot:

```
\renewcommand*{\bibnamedash}{%
  \mlanamedash%
  \iffieldundef{nameaddon}{\adddot}{\nopunct}}
```

We don't need to worry about the space delimiting the dash and the `nameaddon` field because biblatex-mla's `author` bibliography macro issues `\setunit{\addspace}` before printing `nameaddon`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=mla]{biblatex}

%\renewcommand*{\bibnamedash}{\mlanamedash\nopunct}

\renewcommand*{\bibnamedash}{%
  \mlanamedash%
  \iffieldundef{nameaddon}{\adddot}{\nopunct}}

% biblatex-mla has no localization module for German
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  print = {print}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@INCOLLECTION{gaonkar:in,
  author = {Gaonkar, Dilip Parameshwar},
  title = {On Alternative Modernities},
  pages = {1--23},
  nameaddon = {Name add-on},
  editor = {Gaonkar, Dilip Parameshwar},
  booktitle = {Alternative Modernities},
  publisher = {Duke University Press},
  location = {Durham and London},
  date = {2001},
  isbn = {0-822-32714-7}}
@COLLECTION{adorno-gs2,
  editor = {Rolf Tiedemann},
  year = {2003},
  maintitle = {Gesammelte Schriften Bd. 10.2},
  mainsubtitle = {Kulturkritik und Gesellschaft II. Eingriffe. Stichworte},
  publisher = {Suhrkamp},
  location = {Frankfurt am Main},
  author = {Theodor W. Adorno},
  howpublished = {Print},
  options = {useeditor=false},
  shortauthor = {{In: GS 10.2}}}
@COLLECTION{adorno-gs8,
  editor = {Rolf Tiedemann},
  year = {2003},
  maintitle = {Gesammelte Schriften Bd. 8},
  mainsubtitle = {Soziologische Schriften I},
  publisher = {Suhrkamp},
  location = {Frankfurt am Main},
  author = {Theodor W. Adorno},
  howpublished = {Print},
  options = {useeditor=false},
  shortauthor = {{In: GS 8}}}
@INCOLLECTION{adorno-spaet,
  author = {Theodor W. Adorno},
  title = {Sp\"{o}tkapitalismus oder Industriegesellschaft?},
  year = {1968},
  subtitle = {Einleitungsvortrag zum 1. Deutschen Soziologentag},
  pages = {354-370},
  crossref = {adorno-gs8}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{adorno-spaet,adorno-gs2,adorno-gs8}
\nocite{gaonkar,gaonkar:in,knuth:ct,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here's the output without dots:

[image]

And with dots:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this swift response! However, using that solution bears another problem: incollection entries have no delimiter after \mlanamedash. This weren’t a problem if collections had none as well, but two different ways of delimiting entries seems strange. To try it out, insert the following entry in above example: @INCOLLECTION{adorno-spaet,
  author = {Theodor W. Adorno},
  title = {Spätkapitalismus oder Industriegesellschaft?},
  year = {1968},
  subtitle = {Einleitungsvortrag zum 1. Deutschen Soziologentag},
  pages = {354-370},
  crossref = {adorno-gs8},
  shortauthor = {Adorno},
}

Comment: @Jakob I've made an edit.

Comment: Wow, that really should cover the problem as it exists right now! I didn’t understand the biblatex documentation recommends using title in favour of maintitle, but if that solves the problem already, just the better (and admittedly, the appendix shows this quite clearly, though). Thus, I hope to be able to avoid downgrading to biblatex 1.0 and use it properly now. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Jakob No problem. You might also want to reconsider use of the `howpublished` field. biblatex-mla has no `lbx` file for German. In the example I make use of `\DefineBibliographyStrings` to give a string for `print`.

Comment: Ah, now I see it essentially boils down to an error of mine! Since these entries don’t have urls I’ll use your `\DefinBibliographyStrings` code instead of adding a `howpublished` field to each single entry. Although biblatex has `mvbooks` I think that `(in)collection` does a better job since `biblatex-mla` lists the `incollections` separately after the `collections`, which no other authortitle style I tried did.

Comment: @Jakob This is because biblatex-mla uses the `book` driver for `collection`. In standard styles `collection` entries can be sorted by `editor`, not `author`. There are a variety of ways around this - use `book`/`inbook`, fields to override sort order or a modified `collection` driver. I wouldn't overlook any of the standard styles, unless you're having to strictly follow the MLA style.

Answer (score 0):

@Audrey, thanks for helping Jacob out here. I've just incorporated your improved bibnamedash into an updated version of Biblatex-mla. Since I've been partially neglecting Biblatex-mla and partially just remiss at spinning off new releases, I'm now hosting my files on GitHub in hopes people are able to download updates between major releases as well. Here's the URL of the branch which is in-progress: https://github.com/jmclawson/biblatex-mla/tree/dev