# Citing in mla style using & adjusting authortitle-ticomp (and not biblatex-mla)

Tags: spacing, biblatex, mla-style

### MLA without `biblatex-mla`

I'd like to set a document conforming to the MLA style. As I was [recommended elsewhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50103/biblatex-mla-bibliography-one-redundant-dot-in-second-entry-by-same-author-co), I don't want to do this with `biblatex-mla`, but instead use the more robust styles that come shipped with biblatex, in this case `authortitle-ticomp`.

### What I've done so far

Not striving to do a 100% complete reimplementation, I'd be quite satisfied if the inline citations would adhere as close as possible to the MLA guidelines.

I have so far done the following changes:

1. removed the pagination prefix
2. removed "`ibid`"
3. removed the `\postnotedelim`

### The problem starts here

and 3. is exactly what causes me (small) headaches: Since I redefined (or rather, deleted) `\postnotedelim` I have no space between the `title` and the `page` field in the citation. In subsequent citations, this is fine, as there is no space needed (see minimal example).
It is no big problem to insert an extra space in the `postnote` before the page number, but there surely must be a way to circumvent this?

Other than that, do you have any other suggestions to adhere closer to mla style while still employing `authortitle-ticomp`?

### Minimal example

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authortitle-ticomp]{biblatex}

% 1. delete pagination prefix
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
% 3. delete "ibid" in subsequen quotes
\DefineBibliographyStrings{british}{%
ibidem = {{}{}}}
% 3. delete comma and space in front of pagenumber
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{jmcdis,
author = {J. M. Coetzee},
title = {Disgrace},
year = {2000},
publisher = {Vintage},
location = {London}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
"Lucy's secret; his disgrace" \autocite[109]{jmcdis}. And a subsequent
citation \autocite[110]{jmcdis}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of tinkering with the `ibidem` bibstring, redefine the `cite:ibid` bibmacro.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authortitle-ticomp]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}

\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addspace}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
%  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}% DELETED
  \ifloccit
    {\global\booltrue{cbx:loccit}}
    {}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{jmcdis,
author = {J. M. Coetzee},
title = {Disgrace},
year = {2000},
publisher = {Vintage},
location = {London}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
"Lucy's secret; his disgrace" \autocite[109]{jmcdis}. And a subsequent
citation \autocite[110]{jmcdis}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if I try this, I get the following: !["Lucy's secret; his disgrace" (Coetzee 109). And a subsequent citation (   ).](http://s4.imgload.info/wv27mc7fxau4mxs.jpg)

Comment: Try to delete al auxiliary file and compile again. Also make sure tu use the current versions of `biblatex`/Biber. If it still doesn't work, you must be doing something different in your actual document.

Comment: Strange, I'm using Archlinux (which is normally quite bleeding edge), `texlive-core` is `2012.26898` and `texlive-bibtexextra` is  `2012.26868`. But `biblatex` is still `1.7 2011/11/13` and `biber` is only `0.9.9` That'll probably be the culprits… I'll see how to update that. Thankn you!

Comment: This is weird. After hours of work I got `biblatex 2.2 (17/08/2012)` and `biber 1.2` on my system. After running pdflatex, biber, pdflatex on the file, I get exactly the same result as in my first comment. What am I doing wrong here? First I thought it might have sth to do with me using latexmk, but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: @Jakob You compiled my example as-is? (BTW, I'm using `latexmk`, too.)

Comment: Yes, I copied it several times but to no avail. As I tried it with `texmaker` and it worked there, I was close to desperation, but then I found the culprit: When I pasted yours to `texmaker`, saved the file, opened & compiled it in `vim`, it worked… seems to have been a copy & paste issue (although `vimdiff` between that version and the one I pasted it into `vim` directly, doesn't show a diff between the files… nevertheless, it works and thus, the first of my questions has now been solved! Thanks! If there's anybody out there having other suggestions, I'd be happy to receive them!

Comment: Ok, I should stop commenting on this issue, but I just wanted to inform you that it (empty brackets in successive citations) now happened again while writing in my usual environment (`vim` + `latexbox`) and I got rid of it by running it once through `texmaker's` `latexmk` config. I'll post more here if I know what is causing this behaviour.

Comment: [Here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100498/12292), Audrey posted a redefinition of the `cite:ibid` macro that does some checks and alterations regarding `postnote` and `prenote` definitions and might be worthwhile to replace yours as it is just a few lines longer? Or do you prefer me posting it as an additional answer as it generally helps adhering closer to using `MLA style` with `authortitle-ticomp`? @lockstep