# How to avoid printing the shorthand label in subsequent quotes of same entry

Tags: biblatex, mla-style

## How to avoid printing the `shorthand` label in each subsequent quote from the same work?

Sticking with the idea of using [MLA with `biblatex` standard styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74416/12292) (in my case `authortitle-ticomp`), I've got a problem with entries that have `shorthand` defined:

Instead of using the `ibid` mechanism, `biblatex` prints the `shorthand` in each subsequent quote from the same work. Would it use `ibid` instead, I could use the [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/74420/12292) from lockstep to redefine the `cite:ibid` macro to make away with `ibid` and thus virtually have mla-style citations.

So for me, the easiest way seems to be to make `biblatex` use `ibid` for entries that have a `shorthand` defined. I'd be equally happy about a solution that would just *not* print the `shorthand` anymore in any subsequent quote of the same text.

I felt that this should be a feature of `biblatex` and posted a [feature request](http://sourceforge.net/p/biblatex/features/157/) quite some time ago, but in the end was referred to TEX.SE for a solution.

### Minimum Working Example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authortitle-ticomp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
% lockstep's solution to have no "ibid"
%\renewbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
%%  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}% DELETED
%  \ifloccit
%    {\global\booltrue{cbx:loccit}}
%    {}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@INBOOK{adorno:halbbildung,
  author = {Theodor W. Adorno},
  title = {Theorie der Halbbildung},
  year = {1959},
  pages = {93-121},
  shorthand = {Halbbildung},
  booktitle = {Gesammelte Schriften Band 8},
  booksubtitle = {Soziologische Schriften I},
  editor = {Rolf Tiedemann},
  publisher = {Suhrkamp},
  location = {Frankfurt am Main},
  options = {useeditor=false},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
A quote \autocite[93]{adorno:halbbildung}. A second one \autocite[94]{adorno:halbbildung}. A third one \autocite[94]{adorno:halbbildung}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Feature requests to address style issues are often rejected. Users are instead encouraged to customize the relevant commands, macros and drivers in the document preamble or biblatex configuration file.

For your problem, shorthands can easily be suppressed in a recurrent citation using the `\AtEveryCitekey` hook. The *ibidem* citation label can be avoided by redefining the `cite:ibid` macro, but it should only be omitted when the `postnote` field is defined. Moreover, if `prenote` is defined we should also suppress punctuation that would otherwise delimit the postnote and the label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authortitle-ticomp]{biblatex}

\AtEveryCitekey{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
    {\clearfield{shorthand}}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:ibid}{%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\bibstring[\mkibid]{ibidem}}}
    {\iffieldundef{prenote}
       {}
       {\nopunct}}%
  \ifloccit
    {\global\booltrue{cbx:loccit}}
    {}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
Filler text \autocite[93]{kant:kpv}. Filler text \autocite{kant:kpv}.
Filler text \autocite[94]{kant:kpv}. Filler text \autocite[93]{kant:ku}.
Filler \autocite[e.g.][10]{kant:ku}. \Textcite{kant:ku} showed that...
\Textcite[10--15]{kant:ku} showed that...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Audrey for that nice solution! Can I add this answer as additional answer to my [other post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/74416/12292) as especially the check on pre/postnote would enhance the answer by @lockstep there or would that be theft and should only be done by the original author?

Comment: @Jakob No problem. It isn't much of a departure from lockstep's answer, so you could simply leave a comment on his post to consider updating it. (I'm pretty sure pinging him from here won't work.)